# OO correctness - inheritance hierarchy - who creates objects that the other objects use?

Tags: c++, oop

I'm implementing something based off of some OO diagrams, but the inheritance is deep and I'm a little confused about who needs to instantiate objects that are used to create the other objects.  The diagram looks like this:

> IFCa is an IFCCBase
>
> IFCCBase is an IFC
>
> IFC is an IFO
>
> IFP is an IFO
>
> IFCC is an IFCCBase
>
> IFCC *has a* IFP
>
> IFCa is a IFC
>
> IFCCBase *has a* M, and a vector of shared pointers of IFC

The code for IFCC, IFCCBase, and IFC don't do much yet.  This is an example of my code in question:

IFP.h:

```
#include "IFO.h"
#include "IFCCBase.h"
#include "IFCC.h"
#include "IFC.h"

class IFP: public IFO{
public:
  IFP(IFO* pParent, param, param, param, param);

private:
  IFC *m_C;
  IFCCBase *m_IFCCBase;
  IFCC *m_IFCC;
};
```

IFP.cpp:

```
#include "IFP.h"

IFP::IFP(IFO* pParent, param, param, parm, param): IFO(pParent)
{
  m_C = new IFC(pParent);
  m_IFCCBase = new IFCCBase(m_C);
  m_IFCC = new IFCC(m_IFCCBase);
}
```

So this is my question.  To create an IFCC, I needed to instantiate two objects which were created from the one before.  Does that belong in IFP's constructor, or should they have been provided in IFP's parameter list from somewhere else?  It's tough since I'm not familiar with the domain and it's been a while since I had to think about OO design like this.

I will be checking this post on and off since our company is basically shut down between Christmas and the New Year.

Comment: this sounds almost like the iostreams classes. ungood.

Comment: It'll be so much easier to understand what you are trying to do had the names of your classes been something one could relate to.

Comment: @Alf - not IOStreams.  Why do you think it's ungood?  Where is iostream implementation that I would compare with to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I talked to the team now that everybody is back from vacation, and it turns out that, for IFP, instead of

```
  m_C = new IFC(pParent);
  m_IFCCBase = new IFCCBase(m_C);
  m_IFCC = new IFCC(m_IFCCBase);
```

it needed

```
  m_IFCC = new IFCC(this);
```

Plus, the other classes in IFCC hierarchy (IFC, IFCCBase) receive a generic IFO instead of the explicit parent class.

That way, IFP doesn't know about the entire hierarchy of its class member, and the info is passed that our domain requires.  Plus, it's not deemed as circular by the compiler.  It's a very different setup, and I guess it wasn't something people could easily answer, correctly, here, and I hadn't realized it.  Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Based on a direct implementation of the relationships you described, you would have this:

```
struct M {
};

struct IFO {
};

struct IFC : IFO {
};

struct IFP : IFO {
};

struct IFCCBase : IFC {
  M m;
  std::vector<std::shared_ptr<IFC> > ifc_ptrs;
};

struct IFCa : IFCCBase {
};

struct IFCC : IFCCBase {
  IFP ifp;
};
```

There isn't necessarily any need for pointers or `new`.

There are various reasons why you might want to have pointers, have them allocated somewhere else, and pass them into the constructor, but unless there is a good reason to do otherwise, just do the simplest thing.

Comment: I can't use struct's here.  Any other thoughts?  Has to be separate classes.

Comment: I wasn't looking for a new class use/layout.  I'm trying to figure out the best way to create the IFCC.

Comment: @Michele: `struct`s are classes.  The only difference between using the keyword `struct` and `class` is whether the access is public or private by default.

Comment: @Michele: What I've shown has the layout you described.

Comment: you aren't answering my question.

Comment: @Michele: I guess I don't understand your question.

Comment: I'm not looking for a different class implementation than my layout.  I'm trying to decide if I should be instantiating the objects that make up m_C/m_IFCC/m_IFCCBase in my IFP constructor, or if they should be a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: @Michele: If those are the only two choices, I would say there isn't enough information in your question to answer it. Each choice has its pros and cons. Passing pointers to related classes to the constructor is a common way to make classes more easily unit-testable for example, but it makes using the class less convenient in the normal case.

Comment: Thanks for the ideas @Vaugn Cato.  I talked with my team member today and they want each class to link to the creator (parameter in constructor), because of our domain, but otherwise I could have had empty constructors. I realize there was a lot of info missing about the project, but wasn't sure if there was a general design consideration.